# How do I solve "django.db.utils.OperationalError: near "CASCADE": syntax error" in GeoNode install?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geonode

I have followed the [Advanced Installation instructions for GeoNode Project](https://docs.geonode.org/en/master/install/advanced/project/index.html), but at the *Run GeoNode Project for the first time in DEBUG Mode* step, it says to execute:

```
# Prepare the GeoNode Spatialite database (the first time only)
cd src/
chmod +x paver_dev.sh
./paver_dev.sh setup
./paver_dev.sh sync
```

I should note that I am not running `paver_dev.sh`, but rather `paver.sh`. Here is the output when running `./paver.sh sync`:

```
./paver.sh: line 1: /home/geonode/.override_env: No such file or directory
---> pavement.sync
 python -W ignore manage.py makemigrations --noinput
Migrations for 'ratings':
  /home/geonode/.virtualenvs/my_geonode/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pinax/ratings/migrations/0004_auto_20230223_0126.py
    - Alter field category on overallrating
    - Alter field category on rating
Migrations for 'upload':
  /home/geonode/.virtualenvs/my_geonode/lib/python3.10/site-packages/geonode/upload/migrations/0040_auto_20230223_0126.py
    - Alter field max_number on uploadparallelismlimit
    - Alter field max_size on uploadsizelimit
 python -W ignore manage.py migrate --noinput
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: account, actstream, admin, announcements, auth, avatar, base, br, contenttypes, django_celery_results, documents, favorite, geoapps, geonode_client, geonode_mapstore_client, geonode_resource_processing, geonode_themes, groups, guardian, harvesting, invitations, layers, management_commands_http, maps, monitoring, oauth2_provider, people, pinax_notifications, processing, ratings, resource, sequences, services, sessions, sites, socialaccount, taggit, tastypie, upload, user_messages
Running migrations:
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  Applying taggit.0001_initial... OK
  Applying taggit.0002_auto_20150616_2121... OK
  Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name... OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
  Applying auth.0002_alter_permission_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0003_alter_user_email_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0004_alter_user_username_opts... OK
  Applying auth.0005_alter_user_last_login_null... OK
  Applying auth.0006_require_contenttypes_0002... OK
  Applying people.24_initial... OK
  Applying account.0001_initial... OK
  Applying account.0002_email_max_length... OK
  Applying actstream.0001_initial... OK
  Applying actstream.0002_remove_action_data... OK
  Applying actstream.0003_add_follow_flag... OK
  Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0002_logentry_remove_auto_add... OK
  Applying admin.0003_logentry_add_action_flag_choices... OK
  Applying announcements.0001_initial... OK
  Applying announcements.0002_auto_20200311_0959... OK
  Applying auth.0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages... OK
  Applying auth.0008_alter_user_username_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0010_alter_group_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0011_update_proxy_permissions... OK
  Applying auth.0012_alter_user_first_name_max_length... OK
  Applying avatar.0001_initial... OK
  Applying avatar.0002_auto_20200210_1421... OK
  Applying base.24_initial... OK
  Applying layers.24_initial... OK
  Applying services.24_initial... OK
  Applying services.0025_harvestjob... OK
  Applying services.0026_auto_20171130_0600_squashed_0041_auto_20190404_0820... OK
  Applying layers.24_to_26... OK
  Applying layers.26_to_27... OK
  Applying base.24_to_26... OK
  Applying base.26_to_27... OK
  Applying base.0027_auto_20170801_1228_squashed_0037_auto_20190222_1347... OK
  Applying layers.0027_auto_20170801_1228_squashed_0033_auto_20180606_1543... OK
  Applying layers.0028_auto_20200610_0759... OK
  Applying layers.0029_auto_20200610_0803... OK
  Applying layers.0030_auto_20200610_0825... OK
  Applying layers.0031_auto_20200612_1533... OK
  Applying layers.0032_auto_20200612_1544... OK
  Applying services.0027_auto_20190429_0831... OK
  Applying services.0028_remove_service_last_updated... OK
  Applying services.0029_remove_service_created... OK
  Applying base.0028_curatedthumbnail... OK
  Applying base.0029_resourcebase_last_updated... OK
  Applying base.0030_resourcebase_created... OK
  Applying base.0031_auto_20200114_1651... OK
  Applying base.0032_auto_20200115_1121... OK
  Applying base.0033_auto_20200115_1145... OK
  Applying base.0034_auto_20200212_0410... OK
  Applying base.0035_auto_20200212_0428... OK
  Applying base.0036_resourcebase_doi... OK
  Applying base.0037_auto_20200305_1520... OK
  Applying base.0038_configuration... OK
  Applying base.0039_auto_20200321_1338... OK
  Applying base.0038_delete_backup... OK
  Applying base.0040_merge_20200321_2245... OK
  Applying groups.24_initial... OK
  Applying groups.26_to_27... OK
  Applying groups.0027_auto_20180105_1631_squashed_0028_auto_20180606_1543... OK
  Applying groups.0028_auto_20200114_1651... OK
  Applying groups.0029_auto_20200115_1121... OK
  Applying groups.0030_auto_20200221_1107... OK
  Applying groups.0031_auto_20200305_1522... OK
  Applying groups.0031_auto_20200304_1434... OK
  Applying groups.0032_merge_20200306_1153... OK
  Applying base.0038_auto_20200318_0953... OK
  Applying base.0041_merge_20200323_1119... OK
  Applying base.0042_auto_20200414_1554... OK
  Applying base.0043_auto_20200527_0833... OK
  Applying base.0044_resourcebase_bbox_polygon... OK
  Applying layers.0028_auto_20200323_1945... OK
  Applying layers.0033_merge_20200618_2150... OK
  Applying layers.0034_auto_20210329_1458... OK
  Applying layers.0035_auto_20210525_0847... OK
  Applying documents.24_initial... OK
  Applying documents.25_add_documentresourcelink_table... OK
  Applying documents.26_move_data_to_documentresourcelink_table... OK
  Applying documents.27_drop_resource_columns_from_document_table... OK
  Applying documents.0028_auto_20170801_1228_squashed_0035_auto_20190404_0820... OK
  Applying documents.0029_auto_20190429_0831... OK
  Applying documents.0030_auto_20200305_1520... OK
  Applying documents.0031_auto_20201107_2241... OK
  Applying base.0045_auto_20200507_0445... OK
  Applying base.0044_auto_20201001_1514... OK
  Applying base.0046_merge_20201016_0937... OK
  Applying base.0047_resourcebase_attribution... OK
  Applying base.0048_auto_20201116_0914... OK
  Applying base.0049_resourcebase_resource_type... OK
  Applying base.0050_auto_20210201_1008... OK
  Applying base.0051_auto_20210202_1656... OK
  Applying base.0052_auto_20210205_1631... OK
  Applying base.0053_auto_20210223_0905... OK
  Applying base.0054_auto_20210223_1202... OK
  Applying base.0055_auto_20210302_1109... OK
  Applying base.0056_resourcebase_ll_bbox_polygon... OK
  Applying base.0057_resourcebase_metadata_only... OK
  Applying base.0058_thesaurus_order... OK
  Applying base.0059_fill_empty_resource_type... OK
  Applying base.0060_auto_20210512_1658... OK
  Applying base.0061_auto_20211117_1238... OK
  Applying base.0062_resourcebase_extra_metadata... OK
  Applying base.0063_auto_20220128_1042... OK
  Applying base.0064_resourcebase_metadata... OK
  Applying base.0060_resourcebase_state... OK
  Applying base.0061_merge_0060_auto_20210512_1658_0060_resourcebase_state... OK
  Applying base.0062_resourcebase_files... OK
  Applying documents.0032_remove_document_doc_file... OK
  Applying base.0063_alter_resourcebase_files... OK
  Applying base.0064_alter_resourcebase_files... OK
  Applying base.0065_alter_curatedthumbnail_img... OK
  Applying base.0066_resourcebase_data... OK
  Applying base.0067_resourcebase_storetype... OK
  Applying base.0068_rename_storetype_resourcebase_subtype... OK
  Applying base.0069_resourcebase_sourcetype... OK
  Applying base.0070_auto_20210720_1709... OK
  Applying base.0071_remove_resourcebase_ows_url... OK
  Applying base.0072_remove_resourcebase_detail_url... OK
  Applying base.0073_resourcebase_thumbnail_path... OK
  Applying base.0074_drop_curated_thumbs... OK
  Applying base.0075_delete_curatedthumbnail... OK
  Applying base.0076_merge_20220204_1339... OK
  Applying base.0076_auto_20220128_0919... OK
  Applying base.0077_merge_20220204_1347... OK
  Applying base.0078_alter_resourcebase_metadata... OK
  Applying base.0079_alter_resourcebase_alternate... OK
  Applying base.0080_alter_resourcebase_uuid... OK
  Applying base.0081_alter_resourcebase_alternate... OK
  Applying base.0082_remove_dialogos_comment...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/geonode/.virtualenvs/my_geonode/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 82, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "/home/geonode/.virtualenvs/my_geonode/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 421, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query)
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "CASCADE": syntax error

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/geonode_custom/my_geonode/src/manage.py", line 31, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/geonode/.virtualenvs/my_geonode/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/geonode/.virtualenvs/my_geonode/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/geonode/.virtualenvs/my_geonode/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/geonode/.virtualenvs/my_geonode/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/geonode/.virtualenvs/my_geonode/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 89, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/geonode/.virtualenvs/my_geonode/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 244, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
  File "/home/geonode/.virtualenvs/my_geonode/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/geonode/.virtualenvs/my_geonode/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/geonode/.virtualenvs/my_geonode/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 227, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/home/geonode/.virtualenvs/my_geonode/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 126, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/home/geonode/.virtualenvs/my_geonode/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/special.py", line 105, in database_forwards
    self._run_sql(schema_editor, self.sql)
  File "/home/geonode/.virtualenvs/my_geonode/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/special.py", line 130, in _run_sql
    schema_editor.execute(statement, params=None)
  File "/home/geonode/.virtualenvs/my_geonode/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 145, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/geonode/.virtualenvs/my_geonode/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/geonode/.virtualenvs/my_geonode/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/home/geonode/.virtualenvs/my_geonode/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/home/geonode/.virtualenvs/my_geonode/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in _execute
    with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
  File "/home/geonode/.virtualenvs/my_geonode/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/geonode/.virtualenvs/my_geonode/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 82, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "/home/geonode/.virtualenvs/my_geonode/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 421, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: near "CASCADE": syntax error


Captured Task Output:
---------------------

---> pavement.sync
 python -W ignore manage.py makemigrations --noinput
 python -W ignore manage.py migrate --noinput

Build failed running pavement.sync: Subprocess return code: 1
```

My vague understanding is that the `CASCADE` syntax is incompatible with the internal SQLite functionality, but I don't understand how to force it to use the PostGIS databases I set up earlier. How can I resolve this and get my GeoNode instance running in debug mode?

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: Spatialize is no longer supported on Geonode, please use a Postgres db with PostGIS instead

To setup-up, a PostgreSQL database is enough to change the `GEODATABASE_URL` and `DATABASE_URL`. Plus remember to set up the `env` file before running GeoNode:

```
set -a && . ./.env && set +a
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I have shared a photo on how I resolved the problem, I just changed the "DATABASE_URL" in the "settings.py" which by default was set to SpatiaLite. Instead, I have used the database for the PostgreSQL as shown in the picture.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).